# Disable EditText editability and focus (like TextView)

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

Is there a way to make `EditText` behaviors like `TextView` in Android (XML is prefered)?
I have tried the following:

```
 android:editable="false"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
 android:cursorVisible="false"
 android:longClickable="false"
```

This works but I still can touch the `EditText` to get focus (the orange boarder), though the focus lost as soon as I remove my finger.
I'm not sure what `focusableInTouchMode` does, but it doesn't remove the focus when I keep touching.

And the reason why I don't use a white background `TextView` instead is that the `TextView`'s background is ugly. `EditText`'s background has round corners and shadow effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`EditText` and `TextView` are quite similar. The only difference I see hard-coded into [EditText.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/EditText.java) is to set the editable default to true, which you've set manually. Other than that, the `EditText` [style](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml) is:

```
<style name="Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

and `TextView` is:

```
<style name="Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>
```

My guess is that `@android:drawable/edit_text` is the source of the orange box. Indeed, [it contains](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable/edit_text.xml):

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed"/>
```

The simplest way might be to set its background to the default one:

`android:background="@android:drawable/textfield_default"`

Comment: Thanks for the source code. I'm not sure whether `@drawable/textfield_pressed` is built-in, but eclipse gives me an error for it. After I look at your source code, I notice that I should also turn off `android:clickable`, and it really works!

Comment: Great! So the answer was to turn off android:clickable? By the way, the correct way to reference textfield_pressed is @android:drawable/textfield_pressed

Answer (score 6):

Disable EditText editability and focus (like TextView).

Try this :

```
android:longClickable="false"
android:clickable="false"    
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:editable="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

How many diffrent and wrong ways(
Use always

```
myEditText.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I get a new way. Since I turned off most features of `EditText`, it should be better to think how to "beautify" the ugly white background of `TextView`. And the answer is in the source code:
Just adding `android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"` to a `TextView` makes the same effects.
Thanks again Matthew.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `your_edit_text.setKeyListener(null);` simply to make it un-editable..

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `EditText` not editable or focusable (just like a `TextView`) but with the correct background, you can use the attribute `?editTextBackground` on a `TextView`. If you use drawables like `@android:drawable/edit_text` it will not use a background dependent on the api version.

This:

```
  <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

has the same UI properties of this:

```
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="?editTextBackground"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make EditText not touchable:

```
android:enabled="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

To make EditText look like TextView:

`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`