# How to make textview focus like Edittext Focus in ScrollView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing application with some edittext's and some textviews. Those all are in scrollview. When touch on edittext the soft key is appearing and the view automatically adjusted. The selected edit text is appearing above the soft key. And when click on textview i am showing some hidden view(Linear layout contains 3 buttons) that covers my selected textview field. I am not getting how can i give the same functionality like edittext which can be move my selected textview to above my custom popup.
Please suggest me is there any way to give the focus function like edittext for textview in scrollview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` and `TextView` are quite similar. The only difference I see hard-coded into [EditText.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/EditText.java) is to set the editable default to true, which you've set manually. Other than that, the `EditText` [style](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml) is:

```
<style name="Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

refered from [Disable EditText editability and focus (like TextView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359420/disable-edittext-editability-and-focus-like-textview)

and `TextView` is:

```
<style name="Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>
```

My guess is that `@android:drawable/edit_text` is the source of the orange box. Indeed, [it contains](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable/edit_text.xml):

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed"/>
```

The simplest way might be to set its background to the default one:

`android:background="@android:drawable/textfield_default"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't want to set background for my textview. I am trying to scroll my textview even if my custom pop appear in bottom.