# Unable to make EditText multi-line

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am making an Android app for storing notes. I have made my editText behave like textView before button click. Clicking on edit button makes the editText take value. Now problem arises when i save that value and when it is displayed. EditText doesnt come in multi-line as I want but in a single line.

I declared the inputType property of editText as multi-line in xml file but in the code upon initialising the editText i set its inputType property as null in an attempt to make it both null and multi-line but alas! It doesn't happen.

Below is my xml and java code:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="@color/colorToolBar"
    android:id="@+id/idToolbarNoteDetails"
    android:padding="10dp"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/idFloatingActionButtonEdit"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Colors: "
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/idTextViewColors"
    android:layout_below="@+id/idToolbarNoteDetails"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/idColorRed"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/idToolbarNoteDetails"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idTextViewColors"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_circle_red" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/idColorBlue"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/idToolbarNoteDetails"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idColorRed"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_circle_blue"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/idColorGreen"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/idToolbarNoteDetails"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idColorBlue"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_circle_green"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/idTextViewColors"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:hint="Title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/idEditTextTitle"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/idEditTextTitle"
    android:hint="Content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/idEditTextContent"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/idEditTextTag"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:hint="#TAG"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/idFloatingActionButtonSave"
    android:layout_above="@+id/idFloatingActionButtonEdit"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

**JAVA**

```
package mynotes.pawanjotsingh.com.mynotes.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import mynotes.pawanjotsingh.com.mynotes.R;
import mynotes.pawanjotsingh.com.mynotes.adapters.RecyclerAdapter;
import mynotes.pawanjotsingh.com.mynotes.dbhelper.DataBaseHelper;
import mynotes.pawanjotsingh.com.mynotes.models.NoteModel;

public class NoteDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

enum Colors{RED, BLUE, GREEN, WHITE}

DataBaseHelper  dataBaseHelper;
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonEdit,floatingActionButtonSave;
EditText editTextTitle,editTextContent,editTextTag;
String stringTitle,stringContent,stringTag;
TextView textViewColors,textViewRed,textViewBlue,textViewGreen;
Toolbar toolbar;
int color,colorRed,colorBlue,colorGreen;

String id="";

Colors currentBackgroundColour = Colors.WHITE;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_details);

    editTextTitle=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEditTextTitle);
    editTextTitle.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    editTextContent=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEditTextContent);
    editTextContent.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    editTextTag=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEditTextTag);
    editTextTag.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.idToolbarNoteDetails);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Edit");

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    dataBaseHelper=new DataBaseHelper(this);

    textViewColors=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTextViewColors);
    textViewRed=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.idColorRed);
    textViewBlue=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.idColorBlue);
    textViewGreen=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.idColorGreen);

    colorRed=Color.parseColor("#FE7676");
    colorBlue=Color.parseColor("#76FEEC");
    colorGreen=Color.parseColor("#99FE76");

    stringTitle=getIntent().getStringExtra("text_title");
    stringContent=getIntent().getStringExtra("text_content");
    stringTag=getIntent().getStringExtra("text_tag");
    id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    color=getIntent().getIntExtra("color", Color.WHITE);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(color);


    editTextTitle.setText(stringTitle);
    editTextContent.setText(stringContent);
    editTextTag.setText(stringTag);


    floatingActionButtonSave=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.idFloatingActionButtonSave);
    floatingActionButtonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           save();
        }
    });


    floatingActionButtonEdit=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.idFloatingActionButtonEdit);
    floatingActionButtonEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            floatingActionButtonSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation animationLeft=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move_left);
            floatingActionButtonSave.startAnimation(animationLeft);

            textViewColors.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation animationDown= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move_down);
            textViewColors.startAnimation(animationDown);

            textViewRed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewRed.startAnimation(animationDown);

            textViewBlue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewBlue.startAnimation(animationDown);

            textViewGreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewGreen.startAnimation(animationDown);
            editNote();


        }
    });

    textViewRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentBackgroundColour=Colors.RED;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FE7676"));
        }
    });

    textViewBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentBackgroundColour=Colors.BLUE;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#76FEEC"));
        }
    });

    textViewGreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           currentBackgroundColour = Colors.GREEN;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99FE76"));
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void editNote(){


    editTextTitle.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    editTextTitle.setFocusable(true);
    editTextTitle.requestFocus();

    editTextContent.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);


    editTextTag.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);



}

public void save() {


    int colour=Color.WHITE;

    switch (currentBackgroundColour){
        case RED:
            colour = colorRed;
            break;
        case BLUE:
            colour = colorBlue;
            break;
        case GREEN:
            colour = colorGreen;
            break;
    }


    final NoteModel noteModel = new NoteModel();
    noteModel.setTitle(editTextTitle.getText().toString());
    noteModel.setContent(editTextContent.getText().toString());
    noteModel.setTag(editTextTag.getText().toString());
    noteModel.setId(id);
    noteModel.setDate(getDateTime());
    noteModel.setColor(colour);

    boolean isModified=dataBaseHelper.editNote(noteModel);
    if(isModified==true){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Modifications saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      finish();

    }
    else Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to save modifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

**Links to screenshots**

[This image is when I click edit button. This works just fine, text goes to another line.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3xivwyX2Q3NazRtNGp0NXQ1Z1E)

[This image is when i click the save button. The text goes back to single line instead of multi-line.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3xivwyX2Q3NMi1uejNDOENxLVU)

Comment: I assure you, its not :/
I have tried that solution, it doesnt work in my case

Comment: If you're having a problem with editTextContent: You set the inputType to `InputType.TYPE_NULL` in onCreate() and later on you set it to `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`. How is the text displayed if you do not start with `InputType.TYPE_NULL ` but with the other input type ?

Comment: If I remove `InputType.TYPE_NULL` the functionality gets disrupted, although the text becomes multi-line. 
After removing this line the ediTextContent is ready to take values. My target is to make the editTextContent take value only after i click on the edit Button.

Comment: Then one should try to make the EditText "uneditable" while keeping the input type. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359420/disable-edittext-editability-and-focus-like-textview) is helpful

Comment: Okay so i removed `InputType.TYPE_NULL` line and replaced it with `editTextContent.setEnabled(false);` and enabled it on button click, alas! the problem persists :/ 
Clicking the edit button makes the editText come in single line

Comment: you forgot to put the attribute multiLine:true in yours EditText xml

Comment: No man, i have set the inputType property as Multi-line. 

I found the answer by poking around a little more. 
Posting the answer in a minute.
Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so, I knew that the problem arises when I click on the edit button. Clicking the button made the editText single lined automatically even though I had mentioned the InputType as Multi-line in XML very clearly.

What I did to make the editText multi-line after the button click is that I wrote `editTextContent.setSingleLine(false);` in my java file inside the onClick button code. 
And that is it. :)

Comment: Yes, site says I have to wait 48 hours to accept my answer, I'll be able to "check" the mark in 6 more hours. 
Thanks :)